# Async work after response

Tags: http, asynchronous, go, apache-kafka, goroutine

I am trying to implement http server that:

- Calculate farther redirect using some logic
- Redirect user
- Log user data

The goal is to achieve maximum throughput (at least 15k rps). In order to do this, I want to save log asynchronously. I'm using kafka as logging system and separate logging block of code into separate goroutine. Overall example of current implementation:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
)

type log struct {
    RuntimeParam  string `json:"runtime_param"`
    AsyncParam    string `json:"async_param"`
    RemoteAddress string `json:"remote_address"`
}

var (
    producer, _ = kafka.NewProducer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092,localhost:9093",
        "queue.buffering.max.ms": 1 * 1000,
        "go.delivery.reports": false,
        "client.id": 1,
    })
    topicName = "log"
)

func main() {
    siteMux := http.NewServeMux()
    siteMux.HandleFunc("/", httpHandler)
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr: ":8080",
        Handler: siteMux,
        ReadTimeout:  2 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  10 * time.Second,
    }
    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func httpHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    handlerLog := new(log)
    handlerLog.RuntimeParam = "runtimeDataString"
    http.Redirect(w, r, "http://google.com", 301)
    go func(goroutineLog *log, request *http.Request) {
        goroutineLog.AsyncParam = "asyncDataString"
        goroutineLog.RemoteAddress = r.RemoteAddr
        jsonLog, err := json.Marshal(goroutineLog)
        if err == nil {
            producer.ProduceChannel() <- &kafka.Message{
                TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topicName, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
                Value:          jsonLog,
            }
        }
    }(handlerLog, r)
}
```

The questions are:

1. Is it correct/efficient to use separate goroutine to implement async logging or should I use a different approach? (workers and channels for example)
2. Maybe there is a way to further improve performance of server, that I'm missing?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using a goroutine to log--that's actually a good use of a goroutine. You just need to be careful with data races--make sure your `log` and `r` variables are not simultaneously updated. It's impossible from the code you've shown to tell whether there is a problem here. You should run tests with the race detector to help find such problems.

Comment: Still, please consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018458/720999) when working on your design.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Both variables are being used only inside their gouroutines(reading from `r`, writing to `log`) and there is no outside changes to them. If I understand correctly - there shouldn't be race conditions? `-race` flag shows no errors.

Comment: Well, `r` absolutely is not only being used within that goroutine. That variable is passed in from the http Server. But unless you're using middleware or other handlers that keep that request around longer, and modify it, it should be safe.

Comment: `-race` showing no errors is good. But it's not fool-proof. Not all races will be triggered under test conditions, especially depending on how your tests are written. Consider `-race` to be a vital first step, but not the final word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, this is correct and efficient use of a goroutine (as [Flimzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13860/flimzy) pointed in the comments). I couldn't agree more, this is a good approach.

The problem is that the handler may finish executing before the goroutine started processing everything and the request (which is a pointer) may be gone or you may have some races down the middleware stack. I read your comments, that it isn't your case, but in general, you shouldn't pass a request to a goroutine. As I can see from your code, you're really using only `RemoteAddr` from the request and why not to redirect straight away and put logging in the defer statement? So, I'd rewrite your handler a bit:

```
func httpHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(w, r, "http://google.com", 301)
    defer func(runtimeDataString, RemoteAddr string) {
            handlerLog := new(log)
            handlerLog.RuntimeParam = runtimeDataString
            handlerLog.AsyncParam = "asyncDataString"
            handlerLog.RemoteAddress = RemoteAddr
            jsonLog, err := json.Marshal(handlerLog)
            if err == nil {
                producer.ProduceChannel() <- &kafka.Message{
                    TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topicName, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
                    Value:          jsonLog,
                }
            }
        }("runtimeDataString", r.RemoteAddr)
}
```

2. The goroutines unlikely improve performance of your server as you just send the response earlier and those kafka connections could pile up in the background and slow down the whole server. If you find this as the bottleneck, you may consider saving logs locally and sending them to kafka in another process (or pool of workers) outside of your server. This may spread the workload over time (like sending fewer logs when you have more requests and vice versa).

Comment: Valid point about pointer on request, thank you.
However i ran some load testing using yandex-tank, featuring two approaches - with and without goroutine for async logging. To my surprise, 'with goroutine' variation doesn't end up with latency benefit. Both variantion were nearly the same, except that 'with goroutine' spawned more goroutines. Metrics were done using prometheus. I understand that there are a lot of factors, but could it be because of native async of golang, so that any blocking operation return control to scheduler and there is no need for separate goroutine?

Comment: I think, it's the nature of http redirects, the server sends the headers right away, there is no delay. In fact, I edited my version to make the redirect the very first thing, perhaps, it may shave off some milliseconds.

Comment: Tested code called redirect after logging. Farther investigation on your comment showed that position of redirect call doesn't affect latency. I also tried to add sleep after redirect and get response from the server after timeout that was set. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I see your point, it's true the header hasn't been sent till the return. I changed it to defer and it seems that the redirect happens immediately now.

Comment: Direct usage of your code would never execute defer part, because return already happened. Even if return is placed after - defer is still will be executed before function returns, if I understand correctly. Some improvised [test](http://play.golang.org/p/JVM__vaSMBs)

Comment: no, sorry, return wasn't needed there, but defer will be executed after the redirect

Comment: You are right. Go playground forcefully use only 1 thread, so my example was incorrect.